# Xcode 4.5.2 simulator Crashes in main.m file

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

}
```

I get a crash where is starts to say  `return UIApplication`

I am creating an app that is all connected to one tab view and everything works except for one page.  I have multiple other pages that work, but once I get on to that page it crashes on this line of code.

Comment: the Xcode Debugging console log usually has some useful hints as to what might be causing you to crash out... do you see anything in there?

Comment: all it says in the log is that the error in that code, nothing else

Comment: most likely a bug in a nib file or storyboard. Check them for connections to IBOutlets that got removed from your code.

Comment: How do i get to the nib file, and what is the nib file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same maddening issue. I found that constraints were the problem (some could not be resolved). I removed all my constraints (from the detail scene) and it worked again.
The "All Output" section of the debugger gave me the clue I needed in the end. Resetting the simulator and rebooting had no effect. I hope this helps someone.